# Resize large image to smaller size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image 4288x2848 I just need to resize it to 993x264

I did this way.

Create photoshop layer with these settings

- width 993
- height 264
- resolution 72
- color mode - rgb 8bit

Then I have moved large image to this layer. It auto resized to new layer height but lower image quality(blurry)

Then I did this way also.

Open larger size image in photoshop
Image -> Image size
Set width to 993 (it automatically set height to 600)
Then I moved that to new photoshop layer (993x264)

But result was the same. Lower image quality.

Is there any way to resize this larger image to smaller size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately reducing pixel dimensions generally destroy some information too, all details do not exist after the reduction. In addition Photoshop tries to avoid jagged edges by doing some smoothing. Image processing math says it "anti-aliasing". But that depends on used resampling algorithm.

If the image happens to have exact color limits with no blurry transition zones, you can use resampling option "nearest neighbour" in Image > Image Size dialog. It doesn't create any smoothing to avoid jagginess.